# Как правильно: "503 Service Temporarily Unavailable" или "503 Service Unavailable"?

Tags: php, http

1. На php.net отсутствует информация по формату заголовков [header](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.header.php).
2. В спецификации [HTTP/1.0](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/1.0/spec.html#Code503) указано: `503 Service Unavailable`.

В сети встречаются оба формата записи:

```
header('HTTP/1.0 503 Service Unavailable');
header('HTTP/1.0 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable');
```

Так же интересует корректность этих заголовков:

```
header('HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request');
header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
```

Comment: После кода ошибки вы можете написать любой текст, мне так кажется. Программы смотрят на код, а не на текст.

Comment: @Visman Ну да, наверно вы правы. В консоли Google Chrome есть просто столбец Status в котором отображается 503 в обоих случаях.

Comment: таки temporary (по смыслу) https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-10.5.4

Comment: php.net ни в коем случае не является авторитетным источником по этому вопросу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[По стандарту](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.5.4) – "503 Service Unavailable"

Но вы вольны [использовать любую формулировку или вовсе оставить только код](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-6.1.1):

> 6.1.1 Status Code and Reason Phrase

> The Status-Code element is a 3-digit integer result code of the
> attempt to understand and satisfy the request. These codes are fully
> defined in section 10. The Reason-Phrase is intended to give a short
> textual description of the Status-Code. *The Status-Code is intended
> for use by automata and the Reason-Phrase is intended for the human
> user. The client is not required to examine or display the Reason-
> Phrase*.

(курсив мой)

> 6.1.1 Код состояния и поясняющая фраза

> Код состояния — это трехциферный код, обозначающий попытку понять и ответить на запрос. Подобные коды подробно определяются в секции 10. Смысл поясняющей фразы в том, чтобы дать короткое текстовое описание кода состояния. *Предполагается, что код состояния будет обрабатываться машиной, а поясняющую фразу будет читать человек. От клиента не требуется, чтобы он обрабатывал или отображал поясняющую фразу*.

Есть [одна интересная оговорка](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.5) о разнице между временными и постоянными поломками:

> Except when responding to a HEAD request, the
> server SHOULD include an entity containing an explanation of the
> error situation, and whether it is a temporary or permanent
> condition. User agents SHOULD display any included entity to the
> user

> На все запросы кроме HEAD [к ответу со статусом 5хх]  сервер ДОЛЖЕН добавлять данные о ситуации, в которой произошла ошибка, а также о том, является проблема постоянной или временной. Пользовательские агенты [например, браузеры] ДОЛЖНЫ отображать пользователю любые приложенные данные.

Итог:

- Вам не стоит беспокоиться о формулировке поясняющей фразы. Почти наверняка пользователь её не увидит, а программы вообще не должны её учитывать.
- Вы должны приложить к ответу 5xx данные о том, почему произошла ошибка и является ли она постоянной или временной. Наверняка пользователь увидит эти данные.

По субъективному опыту, хорошим тоном в GET-запросах является специальная страница, которая говорит о том, что случилась какая-то ошибка, но о ней уже известно и идёт работа над тем, чтобы её исправить.